# Get predefined value from a select quesy when no rows returned

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My query is like:

```
SELECT 
    col1, col2, sum(col3), ref
FROM tbl1
LEFT JOIN tbl2 on tbl2.ref = tbl1.ref
WHERE ref in (1,2,3,4,5,...);
```

The result in PHP looks like:

```
[
    0 => [
        'col1' => 'x',
        'col2' => 'y',
        'col3' => 1234,
        'ref'  => 1,
    ],
    1 => [
        'col1' => 'x',
        'col2' => 'y',
        'col3' => 1234,
        'ref'  => 3,
    ],
    2 => [
        'col1' => 'x',
        'col2' => 'y',
        'col3' => 1234,
        'ref'  => 3,
    ],
    3 => [
        'col1' => 'x',
        'col2' => 'y',
        'col3' => 1234,
        'ref'  => 5,
    ],
]
```

Here since there is no data of ref 2 & 4 is available in tbl only 1,3,5 has been returned.

but I want some default data (at least one row) if no row found of those `ref`,

like:

```
[
    0 => [
        'col1' => 'x',
        'col2' => 'y',
        'col3' => 'z',
        'ref'  => 1,
    ],
    1 => [
        'col1' => null,
        'col2' => null,
        'col3' => null,
        'ref'  => 2,
    ],
    2 => [
        'col1' => 'x',
        'col2' => 'y',
        'col3' => 1234,
        'ref'  => 3,
    ],
    3 => [
        'col1' => 'x',
        'col2' => 'y',
        'col3' => 1234,
        'ref'  => 3,
    ],
    4 => [
        'col1' => null,
        'col2' => null,
        'col3' => null,
        'ref'  => 4,
    ],
    5 => [
        'col1' => 'x',
        'col2' => 'y',
        'col3' => 1234,
        'ref'  => 5,
    ],
]
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a derived table with the values and use a `join`:

```
SELECT tbl.col1, tbl.col2, tbl.col3, r.ref
FROM (SELECT 1 as ref UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 as ref UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 as ref UNION ALL
      SELECT 4 as ref UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 as ref
     ) r LEFT JOIN
     tbl
     ON r.ref = tbl.ref;
```

Comment: actually in practical the list is not only (1,2,3,4,5), it c'd be (1,2,3,...)

Comment: @Amin . . . Just extend the values in the table.